# Op-Amp Superposition

Tags: operational-amplifier, superposition

[image]

I know that by the principle of superposition that $$V_{\text{out}-1}=(1+R_1/R_g)V_{1}-(R_1/R_g)V_{2}$$
$$V_{\text{out}-2}=(1+R_1/R_g)V_{2}-(R_1/R_g)V_{1}$$
Could someone please explain the concept behind this derivation.  Could this have been derived without knowing the principle of superposition?

Answer (score 1):

Those voltages are on the input stage of an instrumentation amplifier.  Usually, you see the difference (Vout2-Vout1) carried through the whole derivation, as this amp has a differential input.

The way to understand the circuit is to realize that the resistor Rg has voltage V2 on one side and V1 on the other, thus you know the current through Rg is $$I_{Rg}=(V2-V1)/Rg,$$ going from the bottom of the diagram to the top. R1 and R2 have the SAME current through them, thus you know Vout1 and Vout2. $$(V_{out2} - V2)/R_1 =(V_1-V_{out1})/R_2=I_{Rg}$$

Answer (score 1):

For ideal opamps the voltage across the differential inputs is zero.

Therefore, the voltage across RG is (V1-V2) and the current I through RG and, therefore, through all 3 resistors is:

**I=(V1-V2)/RG=(Vout1-Vout2)/(2R1+RG)**.

From this: **Vout1-Vout2=(V1-V2)(1+2R1/RG)**

Comment: Careful -- V2 is on the noninverting side

Comment: I rather think that my result is OK because of the difference (Vout1-Vout2). Taking the 3rd opamp into account we then have Vout=-(Vout1-Vout2)(R3/R2)=+(Vout2-Vout1)(R3/R2), OK?

Comment: Right you are -- minus signs on both sides, and its still correct.  Sorry